# Is it ubuntu or my laptop that's the problem?

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, startup

I have bought a freedos Lenovo Ideapad 310 laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on it, and updated main software and packages.

The thing is that the computer takes more than 30 seconds to start. (my desktop pc with win10 boots in less than 10 seconds) so I have serious doubts about my device. I am (almost) sure that this can't be related to Ubuntu which is the most trusted Linux OS.

So I wonder how can I run tests to detect exact issue with my laptop?  Are there any tools that the community uses for this?

Comment: 30 sec booting time is OK. Windows does not shut down, but hibernates. You can setup Ubuntu to hibernate too.

Comment: "leptop" should be "laptop". Putting "yesterday" in quotes is unusual and tomorrow your question becomes inaccurate and would need to be changed to "November 2, 2016". Not major issues but something to think about...

Answer (score 1):

The difference between starting times may have to do with Windows' "fast startup" feature.  It essentially equates Ubuntu's hibernate mode.  Basically, the computer doesn't actually fully shut down when you tell it to turn off.  It just transfers the info in your RAM to your hard drive.

Thus, when you startup your computer, it's not actually running all the startup sequences; it's just sending the info back from your drive to your RAM.

If you want Ubuntu to start up that quickly as well, consider trying to use the hibernate or suspend functions.  You can find official reading [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)